# VersionOne - using with and asof

Tags: versionone

I am trying to get information about Assets using the "asof" property.  I have created a simplified version below to show what I am intending.

In this example, which does not work, I am asking for information about every Timebox (sprint) on its Closed Date. Obviously, each timebox has its own Closed Date and making multiple calls per each to find it's ClosedDate, then re-call with that Date in asof, is not viable.

Any ideas how I could get the equivalent of the YAML query below?

```
from: Timebox
select:
  - Name
  - BeginDate
  - ClosedDate
  - from: Workitems
    select:
      - Name
asof:
  ClosedDate
```

Comment: Michael, are you trying to get this for query.v1 or rest-1.v1 endpoint?

Comment: I forgot about this one. I believe I found the solution.  Will post tomorrow for anyone that comes across it.  Query.v1